# Cannot convert from '...Generic.List<Game02.Human>' to 'Game02.Human'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make functions to "send" NPCs to specific rooms by adding them to the room's humansHere list, and one to get this list (and print it later, but I don't need help with that). But I get this error message:

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Game02.Human>' to 'Game02.Human'`

Once I get that fixed, I'm sure I'll figure out the rest, so feel free to ignore this: I need to know how to call this function for specific rooms. Something like:
`LivingRoom.GetHumansHere()` or `Kitchen.SetHumansHere(_lyndonJohnson)`. Or will this work as it is?

```
public class Room
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [...]

    private List<Human> humansHere;

    public List<Human> GetHumansHere()
    {
        return humansHere;
    }

    public void SetHumansHere(List<Human> x)
    {
        humansHere.Add(x);
    }
}

public class Human : LivingCreature
{
    public int Gold { get; set; }
    public List<InventoryItem> Inventory { get; set; }

    public Human(string name, int currentHitPoints, int maximumHitPoints, int gold) : base(name, currentHitPoints, maximumHitPoints)
    {
        Gold = gold;
    }
}
```

Thank you to Dmitry for making it work, and thank you to  Jonathan for explaining the problem:

> The problem is you are trying to add a LIST of humans to a list rather than a single human to a list

Comment: `humansHere.AddRange(x);` to add all values which are in `x` to `humansHere`; or change method's signature to `public void SetHumansHere(Human x)`

Comment: The problem is you are trying to add a LIST of humans to a list rather than a single human to a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

If you want to add *one* `person` only, change method's signature:

```
public void SetHumansHere(Human person)
{
    if (null == person)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person)); 

    humansHere.Add(person);
}
```

If you want to add a *collection* of `persons` in one go, use `AddRange`

```
// IEnumerable<Human> - let's generalize the method
// and allow to add not only List, but other collections, say, array 
public void SetHumansHere(IEnumerable<Human> persons)
{
    if (null == persons)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(persons)); 

    humansHere.AddRange(persons);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **List.AddRange**, Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the List.

```
public void SetHumansHere(List<Human> x)
{
    humansHere.AddRange(x);
}
```